# Fast algorithm needed for finding tuples from within one list inside tuples of another list. Sets?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have following lists:

```
list_1 = [(0, 1, 7, 6), (1, 2, 8, 7), (2, 3, 9, 8), ...]
list_2 = [(0,1), (1,7), (7,8), (3,9), ...]
```

Both lists have a length of 200000 or more elements.

I need a fast algorithm to check how often an element of `list_2` occurs in an element of `list_1`. In the example above, the second element of `list_2` which is `(1,7)` occurs two times in `list_1`, respectively in the first and second list element.

In my case it is a valid hit, if both numbers are a subset of `list_1` independent of their order. So I thought I go with sets and use `.issubset`.

```
for item1 in list_1:
    count = 0
    for item2 in list_2:
        if set(item2).issubset(set(item1)):
            count += count
    if count == 1:
        do this
    if count == 2:
        do that
```

The data from the lists are structured in a way, that I know upfront, that the variable `count` can only have the values `1` or `2`. And I know that a loop of O(N**2) is not smart at all and that the `if` statements in it do not boost performance. Actually, in my current implementation the elements of `list_2` are already of type `set`, but the snippet above is shorter and easy to read.

I believe that there are smart solutions existing for this task.

My application uses numpy and scipy, so any KD-tree search or similar (if applicable) would also be fine.

**EDIT**

I need to be more specific:

- `list_2` always contains pairs. `list_1` can have 3 or more items per list element.
- in `do this` and `do that` I need to keep track of the corresponding elements and their associations, e.g by using a dictionary.
- there is not more than this to exploit the structure of the data

Comment: Probably will depend on details like how large is your alphabet, is there any exploitable structure in the tuples themselves, etc. Could you provide more background?

Comment: Does list_2 always contain pairs, or is that coincidence?

Comment: I edited the post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first do some preprocessing and build a dictionary keyed by the individual numbers that occur in *list_1* providing each key as value the set of tuples in *list_1* that have that keys.

Then finding the occurrences of a pair from *list_2* is as simple as taking the intersection of the sets found at the two keys, and taking the resulting set's size.

```
list_1 = [(0, 1, 7, 6), (1, 2, 8, 7), (2, 3, 9, 8)]
list_2 = [(0,1), (1,7), (7,8), (3,9)]

# per number as dictionary key, list the tuples from list_1 that contain it
d = dict()
for lst in list_1:
    for v in lst:
        if not v in d: d[v] = set()
        d[v].add(lst)

# for each pair, take the intersection of the corresponding lists in d
result = [(lst, len(d[lst[0]].intersection(d[lst[1]]))) for lst in list_2]

print(result)
```

If you need to actually do something with the found tuples from *list_1*, then you would first gather those tuples *without* taking their number (so `d[lst[0]].intersection(d[lst[1]])`), and do your processing on them based on what `len()` provides (1 or 2).